# How come home gym is less productive than going to the real gym?

Tags: gym, home-exercise

I'm not sure if this is something that other people experience or it's just me but I tend to be way less "physically active" at home during weekends rather than when I go to the gym.

Except the fact that I can use the machines the gym has, at home I have some pretty basic stuff like 4 Kg handles and a carpet where to do push-ups, abs and other stuff, but I find myself being lazy even on the exercises that really don't need machines at all.

Plus I noticed that I get fatigued earlier at home when during repetitions, could it be the small room + my sweat + hot air? I really don't know but I'm nowhere as active as when I go to the gym.

Something else that might play a role is the "competition factor". At home I'm alone and I can watch a die-hard movie or put up some metal music but I'll never be as "competitive" as when I go to the gym. I'm a highly competitive person and I think something that greatly motivates me is to "compete against the others" when doing exercises. It might be silly but it's an hypothesis on something else that might stack up when doing exercises at home vs going to the gym.

Comment: This is really subjective. Some people workout better at home, some people work out better at a gym. Some alone, some in groups.

Comment: People will workout a little harder at a professional gym because 1) People are watching/commenting, 2) Better equipment, maintained equipment, workout atmosphere, 3) Fewer at home distractions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the individual. There is some research into these topic.

You are right about the "competition factor". There were some studies proving [that](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1011339025532)

Another reason is how our brain reacts to the environment. Just like each room has a purpose (i.e. bedroom, kitchen, etc.) and our brain reacts differently (i.e. prepare for sleep, food).
We show some certain physiological, psychological and sociological responses. You can read more [here](http://www.gautamshah.in/PDF/BehJUN08.pdf).

Similarly in the fitness environment, our mind prepares us for the physical exercise.

Also gyms are usually (always?) designed by interior designers, where light, colours and even [round curves](http://emilyanthes.com/data/uploads/anthes-building-around-the-mind.pdf) contribute to your workout/rest.